# Regex: find word with extra characters

Tags: java, regex

I want to find the word "help" in a sentence. That in itself is an easy task. However, in some cases this word may be written as `heelp` or `hhelp`, basically containing more characters than it normally would. Some examples are more realistic than others of course.

The basic regex for finding "help" (looking aside capitalization differences - `(?i)` can cover that) is:

```
(help)
```

However, this regex only detects the straight-forward word, not taking into account extra characters that can be added.

Replacing double characters isn't an option, because there are words where there normally(<---) are double characters after each other.

So using Regex, is there any way I can find the words that have "help" in some or another way?

Test text(with explanation as to whether the regex should find it or not)

```
heelp (match)
help (match)
help (match)
heeeelp (match)
hhhheeeelllllpppp (match)
heeeklp (match)
hlep (no match)
helper (no match)
helperp (no match) 
hhhheeeeekklllllpppp (match)
hpeepr33erlrpetertp (no match)
heplp (match)
hepl (no match)
heeeeellllllllpppppppppppl (no match)
```

Numbers should be ignored.

```
h+e+l+p
```

(looking aside boundaries) would exclude for an instance `heplp`.

And as for the amount of characters of each type, it will vary. That is the reason I can't just make a String array.

And if it is relevant, the programming language I use is Java. Also, the casing isn't important. If necessary, that can be lower-cased before checking, or I can add the case insensitivity flag.

---

**TL:DR;** The goal is to find a word (in this case "help") with the chars in that order when there are other characters in between (that may or may not be the same as the previous characters) the characters in the word that's the detection target (again, in this case, `help`).

Comment: Have a look at the regexp special characters `*` and `+`.

Comment: you can use [\\bh+e+l+p+\\b](https://regex101.com/r/Yoy0Hy/1)

Comment: I assume you mean for "heeeklp" to be "(not find)" since it has a 'k' in it

Comment: `^(h+e+l+p+)$` assuming the word `heeeklp` you don't want to be matched.

Comment: (Lots of back and forth here) but I want `heeeklp` to match as it still contains the word "help" even if it has an irrelevant char in there. I will use this in chat, and in chat spelling is something that often is overseen - I still assume the right char order (help has to be written as help) but I want to find it even if there are more or other chars in between

Comment: If you really don't care about any chars between the word you can use a regex like `"\\bh.*?e.*?l.*?p.*?\\b"` (".*" meany any char 0 or more times and the ? lazy so it gets to the next char in word). But I don't know if that is a good idea :)

Comment: If your aim is really an intelligent chat system as you previously said in a comment, then such a regex would be useless. First, many people permute letters by mistake. So `hlep` may be an actual attempt to ask for `help`. And second, there are many words that contain other word which are *not* intended. Example "Helpers" or "Helicopter". Perhaps the answer about NLP was actually the correct one for your case.

Comment: Would you want "helperp" to match? I.e. three letters between the valid letters "l" and "p".

Comment: @RealSkeptic not really intelligent chat system. I will use it for checking if response contains a given input(and for the question I used "help" as an example) - Personally, I plan to use it for a chat-thingy but the regex should still be applicable for any other scenario. The accepted answer shows regex that can be used to find a word even if it has extra chars, while ignoring wrongly-positioned letters(in the case of "help" it doesn't really matter, but for another word it could have a completely different meaning)

Comment: Please provide more sample input with desired result. Especially "helperp" would be interesting.

Comment: @Yunnosch adding more samples

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine Off topic, but I cannot understand why this question has been downvoted so severely. This really doesn't look legitimate to me. Have you raised this with the mods?

Comment: @skomisa It's mostly a consequence of one-off revenge from a many different users. There's nothing that  really can be done about it, unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to demonstrate required steps to cook a regex for word `help` but the requirements are not clear, rules are not strict hence some drawbacks are usual.

```
\bh+[a-z&&[^e]]*e+[a-z&&[^le]]*l+[a-z&&[^ p  l  e ]]*p+\b
           ^             ^^              ^  ^  ^
           |             ||              |  |--|-> [#2]
           |             ||              |-> [#1]
           |             ||-> Previous char(s) [#2]
           |             |-> [#1]
           |-> Next immediate character [#1]
```

- `[a-z&&[^lep]]` means any letter except `l`, `e` or `p`

Regex to copy / paste:

```
\bh+[a-z&&[^e]]*e+[a-z&&[^le]]*l+[a-z&&[^lep]]*p+\b
```

[Live demo](http://fiddle.re/fzmd7n)

Comment: Character class subtraction is Java specific. Don't try to test it with other engines.

Comment: Using the link you provided, and adding the test string `This is helppp` it doesn't match - meaning it doesn't match inside other words

Comment: if it is the case remove leading and trailing anchors (`^` and `$`) instead add word boundary meta-character: [**`\bh+[a-z&&[^e]]*e+[a-z&&[^le]]*l+[a-z&&[^lep]]*p+\b`**](http://fiddle.re/fzmd7n) @LunarWatcher

Comment: Now it works much better, and it doesn't detect nonsense (that happens to have the words in the right order) - the only thing I need to do at this point is reverse engineer the regex and create a method for it so I can do this with any word. But that shouldn't be be very hard. Just one final question: does the `[a-z&&[^lep]]` regex have to have the chars in a specific order, or does it work as long as it is there?

Comment: To cook the regex you should only know after each letter of word there should be a `+[a-z&&[^*]]` in which `*` means next immediate character and previous ones in each step. And no, order isn't important.

Comment: Working on a method to generate this for any word, but it matches the words as expected

Answer (score 2):

I propose to you the following (general) solution:

1. Compress every word so that there are not any duplicated letter
2. Get a dictionary of words to match
3. Match the word in the dictionary which has the minimum Levenshtein distance

The compression should produce this:

```
heelp -> help
help -> help
heeeelp -> help
hhhheeeelllllpppp -> help
heeeklp -> heklp
hlep -> hlep
helper -> helper
```

The Levenshtein distance (`LD(word1, word2)`) between two words is the number of characters to change to make them equals. Example:

```
hhhheeeelllllpppp -> help -> LD(help, help) = 0, LD(help, helper) = 2 <- help match
heeeklp -> heklp -> LD(heklp, help) = 1, LD(heklp, helper) = 3 <- help match
hlep -> hlep -> LD(hlep, help) = 2, LD(hlep, helper) = 3 <- help match
helper -> helper -> LD(helper, help) = 2, LD(helper, helper) = 0 <- helper match
```

Here's my solution:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LevenshteinDistance {                                               
    private static int minimum(int a, int b, int c) {                            
        return Math.min(Math.min(a, b), c);                                      
    }                                                                            

    public static int computeLevenshteinDistance(CharSequence lhs, CharSequence rhs) {      
        int[][] distance = new int[lhs.length() + 1][rhs.length() + 1];        

        for (int i = 0; i <= lhs.length(); i++)                                 
            distance[i][0] = i;                                                  
        for (int j = 1; j <= rhs.length(); j++)                                 
            distance[0][j] = j;                                                  

        for (int i = 1; i <= lhs.length(); i++)                                 
            for (int j = 1; j <= rhs.length(); j++)                             
                distance[i][j] = minimum(                                        
                        distance[i - 1][j] + 1,                                  
                        distance[i][j - 1] + 1,                                  
                        distance[i - 1][j - 1] + ((lhs.charAt(i - 1) == rhs.charAt(j - 1)) ? 0 : 1));

        return distance[lhs.length()][rhs.length()];                           
    }

  public static String compress(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    Character last_char = null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Character c:chars) {
      if(c != last_char) {
        sb.append(c);
        last_char = c;
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
      String[] strings = {"heelp", "help", "heeeelp", "hhhheeeelllllpppp", "heeeklp", "hlep", "helper"};
      String[] dict = {"help", "helper"};

      String match = "", c;
      int min_distance, distance;
      for(String s : strings) {
        c = compress(s);
        min_distance = computeLevenshteinDistance(c, "");

        for(String d : dict) {
          distance = computeLevenshteinDistance(c, d);
          System.out.println("compressed: "+c+ " dict: "+d+" distance: "+Integer.toString(distance));
          if(distance < min_distance) {
            match = d;
            min_distance = distance;
          }
        }

        System.out.println(s + " matches " + match);
      }
    }                                                                            
}
```

This is the output:

```
compressed: help dict: help distance: 0
compressed: help dict: helper distance: 2
heelp matches help
compressed: help dict: help distance: 0
compressed: help dict: helper distance: 2
help matches help
compressed: help dict: help distance: 0
compressed: help dict: helper distance: 2
heeeelp matches help
compressed: help dict: help distance: 0
compressed: help dict: helper distance: 2
hhhheeeelllllpppp matches help
compressed: heklp dict: help distance: 1
compressed: heklp dict: helper distance: 3
heeeklp matches help
compressed: hlep dict: help distance: 2
compressed: hlep dict: helper distance: 3
hlep matches help
compressed: helper dict: help distance: 2
compressed: helper dict: helper distance: 0
helper matches helper
```

Comment: All though this could be a good system, that would require you know all the different words you can build with those letters. In the case of `help` it isn't a lot, but for other words there could be many more. Still, there is `helping`, `helped` and probably more. Otherwise you risk getting a false positive

Comment: Probably I missed something. In the example you provided, it seems that at least you know the words "help" and "helper", then you try to reduce words with extra chars to those words.
You are right saying that there would be false positives. "helping" can match both "help" and "helper". You could avoid this using a threshold on Levenshtein distance, including the possibility of a word maching nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an easy task, you need a good library for NLP (Natural language processing).

For Java that could be [Apache OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org) project.

For Perl there are modules like [Lingua::Stem](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Lingua-Stem/lib/Lingua/Stem.pod) (if you after *stemming*) or PHP [soundex](http://php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php) (if you are after similar *phonetic* words).

Comment: Why? The task seems pretty simple to solve with a short RegEx, at least it looks that way to me!?

Comment: As xander said, it can be solved without having to drag in NLP. And there is a regex that works as well, so NLP isn't necessary

Answer (score 1):

`\bh+\w{0,1}e+\w{0,1}l+\w{0,1}p+\b`

Tested for javascript on regex101.com to have the desired results for the sample input. It is "tighter" than using using "*", it only allows zero or one stray letter. This matches my impression that you allow correct letters in any number, but wrong letters only one between two correct letters.

Will match "help", with any number (>0) of each of the correct letters in the correct order.
Between each two (groups of) correct letters, one or zero of any other "word" letter (digit, letter, "_") are allowed. The word has to start before with the first correct letter and end with the last correct letter.

In order to more precisely select the allowed letters between the correct letters, you can use `[alltheallowedletters]`, in case you do not like the `\w` set.

I replaced `?` with `{0,1}` to demonstrate the flexibility of that syntax.

Comment: @LunarWatcher *I want heeeklp to match as it still contains the word "help" even if it has an irrelevant char in there* according to this statement a word like `hhhheeeeekklllllpppp` should match too. Shouldn't it?

Comment: It was my impression (now seems confirmed) that ONE wrong letter is OK, but two (or one wrong repeated) is unwanted.

Comment: yes, it should (noticed that actually doesn't work when you wrote that comment). But the base is there, so by doing this: `\bh+\w*?e+\w*?l+\w*?p+\b` (added `*` after `\w`) it works. [Working sample](https://regex101.com/r/WLHENG/1)

Comment: Now it matches so many other bullshits *hpeepr33erlrpetertp* @LunarWatcher

Comment: Sniff. I have to point you to a different answer which seems to be exactly what you described. It is mine with "*" instead of "?"... Sniff.

Comment: Consider using `{0,2}`instead of `?` or `*`. Hope that is java regex.

Comment: What does {0, 2} do?

Comment: Assuming java knows it (not sure) it matches 0,1 or 2 stray letters. That will allow you to balance between enough tolerance and avoiding "so many other b***s***".

Comment: This pattern doesn't generalize unless you care about matching only `help`. Does it mean you would create a new pattern for each new word?

Comment: @Meghi creating a new pattern for a given word could be done using a method appending common parts. Split up a word by the letters, add the appropriate regex before and after and append it to a String(Builder)

Comment: I edited to show the use of `{}`. Try playing with the second number to balance "too tight" against "matches b***s**".

Comment: Limiting the quantifier doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: @revo Why? Seems to be the tuning OP is looking for. He described the effect of `*` in strong and non-approving terms and discovered onyl with delay, that single letter matching is slightly too tight to OPs taste.

Comment: Still, the input can be any given amount of chars; there could be one e or 200 e's followed by 100 k's (an extreme scenario, but it should still detect the word help)

Comment: Then this pattern will match many other words that have `h e l p` in them in the right order but actually have nothing to do with `help`. Now in my sentence, replace `help` with another target word. I bet plenty of words are like that.

Comment: Tried removing the quantifier, but that ignores spaces (thus it matches all the words as one group and one match)

Comment: Any number of h, e, l, p is still matched, because of them being quantified with `+`. Just the stray letters between them are restricted to 0-2. Would you like to give more sample input with desired result?

Comment: I do not understand what you describe in relation to spaces. Any space should prevent the match, shouldn't it? Otherwise give more sample input.

Comment: Using the first test scenario (with `?`) I tried removing those chars - that ended up with the regex ignoring the spaces and matching the entire sample text because it contained `h e l p` in that order

Comment: My main question was about the situation when instead of spaces, there are other letters forming another meaningful word. In NLP, this is a known problem and a standard way of handling this situation is using "edit distance" that I described below. You can see whether it can serve the purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

this works. try on any online regex tester to be sure that it's what you are looking for:
remark: this is for any amount of unwanted letters, if you need 1 letter - "\w*" pattern should be replaced with "\w?" (and in java code accordingly)

`\bh+\w*e+\w*l+\w*p+\b`

updated*

and here is java code to get such regex on any word

```
public static String getRegExForWord(String word){
        char[] chars =  word.toCharArray();
        StringBuilder pattern = new StringBuilder("\\b");
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length-1; i++) {
            pattern.append(chars[i]).append("+\\w*");
        }
        return pattern.append(chars[chars.length - 1]).append("+\\b").toString();
    }
```

Comment: This only works for `help`! Do you mean to define one regex for each word that needs to be captured?!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED VERSION**

```
h = h.trim();
h = h.replaceAll("\\s+", "\n");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(h+.*?e+.*?l+.*?p+)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(h);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: Got a regex101.com tab open with the sample text (`heelp help help heeeelp hhhheeeelllllpppp hlep helper heeklp`) in it. This regex (as it currently stands) reacts to `hlep help` as one group - two errors that is. (It shouldn't react to hlep and it should NOT treat those two as one group)

Comment: Ohh, now I see. I thought you would take in one word at a time. Updated it for a string where the words are separated by spaces only :)

Comment: A bit late, I know, but in my code, all spaces have been replaced by '\n', placing them on a new line.

Comment: The newline-format used in the question is so I could give an overview of example input. Now I think (can't be fully sure) that your answer has a single-word multi-line check.

Comment: Yes it does. Got it. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You know, mine WAS the third answer. And it DOES work perfectly... :(

Comment: The thing is it [doesn't work perfectly](https://regex101.com/r/jjkAQe/1) - it marks `hlep help` as one group and ignores the `er` in the last word

Answer (score 0):

After finding `help` using normal regex, you need to use "edit distance" to find similar patterns. It is a metric used for spell checking and word recommendations. For instance if you return all words that have the edit distance of 1 from help, you will get:

```
helpp
heelp
hellp
hel
belp
...
```

Edit distance of 2 from `help`:

```
heeelp
helppp
hhellp
```

Using NLTK (Python NLP package), this can be achieved by:

```
my_word = 'help'
corpus = {'w1', 'w2'} # Set of all words in your corpus

word_distance = {}

for word in corpus:
    if nltk.edit_distance(my_word, word) <= 2:
        word_distance[word] = nltk.edit_distance(my_word, word)

# Sort dict by value if you choose to return greater edit distances
results = sorted(word_distance, key=word_distance.get, reverse=True)
print(results[:10])
```

You can impose additional restrictions by regex for better results. For instance everything returned by `nltk.edit_distance` is only acceptable if it starts with `h` and ends in `p`.